# Correct configuration of /etc/hosts file for Oracle Forms and Reports on Virtualbox

Tags: oracle

I am trying to do an install of Oracle Forms and Reports on Weblogic 10.3.6. I am using virtual box and Oracle Linux 6.5.
Forms and Reports keeps failing on 'Executing: opmnctl startproc ias-component..'

After looking through what logs are avaiable and searching the net, I think the problem lies with my etc/hosts file - but I do not understand why or how to fix it.

My etc/hosts file consists of
127.0.0.1     localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1           localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost.localdomain6

I also tried changing this file to 
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost4
::1 localhost localhost6

Does anyone know what I should have in this file?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you will leave the hosts file with the defaults and use DNS for name resolution. I would verify the DNS settings for your server. Then use ping to test name resolution.